# Use and call the connection string in the forms/ c#

Tags: c#

I'm building desktop application using c# , I put the connection string in the app.config file like this

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ComputerManagement" 
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=Computersh;Integrated Security=True"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

How I can call the connection string in the forms ?

Comment: Taking into account all answers, don't forget to add reference to `System.Configuration.dll` assembly for accessing `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class

Comment: Its usually bad practice to use connectionstring in the form, create a class that handles database access

Comment: Could you plz send to me useful link how to creat a class to handle the database ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the connection string with `ConfigurationManager`:

```
using System.Configuration;
var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComputerManagement"];
```

But you'll still need to use something to connect to the database with it, such as `SqlConnection`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComputerManagement"];

if (connection != null) 
{
    using (var sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference `System.Configuration` and use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
      .ConnectionStrings["ComputerManagement"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComputerManagement"].ConnectionString;
```

Also you have to add this `using System.Configuration;` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) should suffice:

```
var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComputerManagement"];
```

Then, check for `null`, before accessing the actual string:

```
if (connection != null) {
  var connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
}
```